# How to iterate over StaxEventItemReader/itemreader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Currently I want to access the objects inside StaxEventItemReader. This is done by using StaxEventItemReader.read() (xml-file has 50 objects/items), so that I can do something with these objects.

The question is how you can correctly iterate over the items of StaxEventItemReader?

Originally I had something like this:

```
while (objectStaxEventItemReader.read() != null) {
    invokeRandomMethod(objectStaxEventItemReader.read());
}
```

The problem is that read() "reads a piece of input data and advance to the next one" ([Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html)).
So at the end only 25 items are processed, since the null checks also advance the "iterator".
So null checks seems to be not possible.

Currently I only have a temporary solution (using for loop):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    invokeRandomMethod(objectStaxEventItemReader.read());
}
```

All 50 objects are read, but this is not a satisfactory solution since I have to specify that there are 50 elements.

I tried to look around and found the peek method of PeekableItemReader ([Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/PeekableItemReader.html)) which might have been useful, but it is a subinterface of itemreader, so I can't use it with StaxEventItemReader which just implements itemreader.

***Is there a way to check for null or better way to iterate over StaxEventItemReader without having to specify the amount of elements?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sentinel = objectStaxEventItemReader.read();

while(sentinel != null) {
    invokeRandomMethod(sentinel);
    sentinel = objectStaxEventItemReader.read();
}
```

Save your return value in a variable and check if its null.

Comment: Strange. Your solution seems to be correct on paper, but for some reason when I do it this way, more objects are read than are present, For example I have two objects of type car inside the xml, these two are correctly read, but for some reason I am also reading 40 additional objects of type car (all attributes null) from StaxEventItemReader . Not sure if this is behaviour of StaxEventItemReader which I am not aware of, I guess the problem didn't come up before since I manually specified when to stop reading.

Comment: @TomSteger if you want more help you're going to have to provide more context

Comment: I guess it is fine now. Your simple solution above works just fine, thanks. Since I am using StaxEventItemReader outside the spring batch flow, some extra things have to be handled. After the data is read StaxEventItemReader seems to have multiple objects as well with all attributes set to null. For now I just check if it is a "null object" before passing it to the method.